# How to minimize an objective function containing frobenius and nuclear norms?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, cvxpy, convex-optimization, cvxopt

[image]

subject to the constraint that square of Frobenius norm of Ds matrix has to be less than or equal to 1.

Currently I am using [CVXPY](https://www.cvxpy.org/) library to solve the objective function. My code sample looks like

```py
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np


np.random.seed(1)
Xs = np.random.randn(100, 4096)
Ys = np.random.randn(100, 300)

# Define and solve the CVXPY problem.
Ds = cp.Variable(shape=(300, 4096))

lamda1 = 1

obj = cp.Minimize(cp.square(cp.norm(Xs - (Ys * Ds), "fro")) + lamda1 * cp.norm(Ds, "nuc"))
constraints = [cp.square(cp.norm(Ds, "fro")) <= 1]

prob = cp.Problem(obj, constraints)
prob.solve(solver=cp.SCS, verbose=True)
```

The console gives an error that

> Solver `'SCS'` failed. Try another solver or solve with verbose=True for more information. Try re-centering the problem data around 0 and re-scaling to reduce the dynamic range.

I event tried to experiment with different solvers like `cp.ECOS` but they do not optimize the function.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: The problem is DCP (I have verified it using prob.is_dcp()). Hope this helps

Comment: You can solve it using Projected Sub Gradient Method or ADMM. I can do it in MATLAB.